# Two HTTP 1.1 request (one doesnt work)?

Tags: perl, io-socket

I am about to lose it here, i am trying to send two HTTP 1.1 to get the source code of some of my url pages (I dont want to use LWP), and only the first one works, even when i switch the order, so in theory both requests are fine, here is what i do :

I even created two sockets just in case, but same result ...

```
my $sock =  IO::Socket::INET->new(
                PeerAddr => $dom,
                PeerPort => 'http(80)',
                Proto    => 'tcp'
            )
            or die "Could not connect to :80!! $!";

my $sock2 =     IO::Socket::INET->new(
                PeerAddr => $dom,
                PeerPort => 'http(80)',
                Proto    => 'tcp'
            )
            or die "Could not connect to :80!! $!";         


my $req2 = << 'EOT'
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: $dom
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 57
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: ${org}
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: ${ref}


EOT
;




my $req = << 'EOT'
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: $dom
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 57
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: ${org}
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: ${ref}


EOT
;           



$sock2->send($req2);


sleep 5;


my $abc;
while(<$sock2>) {
        print $_;
    }


$sock->send($req);


sleep 5;


while(<$sock>) {
        print $_;
    }
```

Where seems to be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debugging tip: print out the requests before you send them. You'll discover that you should have used double-quoted strings for your requests so that the variables get interpolated → `<<"EOT"`. Furthermore, I find your lack of explicit `\r\n` line endings disturbing. Productivity tip: seriously, just use [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) instead of bare sockets for HTTP requests. What's wrong with LWP?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with LWP to be honest, it is just a little slower, cuz sometimes i need to check multiple pages, and with the HTTP 1.1 i dont have to wait for the answer, well this is what i have been told.

Comment: Whoever told you this was wrong. LWP does use HTTP/1.1 and also understands HTTP/1.1 responses, contrary to your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You send a HTTP/1.1 request with keep-alive (which is implicit with HTTP/1.1, so you could skip the Connection header). But, you don't make any attempts to parse the HTTP response, but just assume that it will close the connection when the request is done. This is plain wrong.

I really recommend you to use established HTTP libraries like LWP, HTTP::Tiny ... and not try it on your own. If you really want to do it please read the relevant standard, e.g. RFC 2616 which explains all the important stuff you simply ignore: http response header and body, content-length vs. chunked encoding, content-encodings etc. HTTP/1.1 is not that simple - if you want it simple use HTTP/1.0 and do not use keep-alive.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but when instantiating the second socket just after the first send, re-instantiating the first socket it does work, at first i thought it was because i didnt close the first socket, but even with that `close($socket)` it doesnt work unless i use it like this :

```
my $sock =  IO::Socket::INET->new(
                PeerAddr => $dom,
                PeerPort => 'http(80)',
                Proto    => 'tcp'
            )
            or die "Could not connect to :80!! $!";


my $req2 = <<"EOT"
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: $dom
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 57
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: ${org}
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: ${ref}


EOT
;




my $req = <<"EOT"
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: $dom
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 57
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: ${org}
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: ${ref}


EOT
;           



my $sock2 =     IO::Socket::INET->new(
                PeerAddr => $dom,
                PeerPort => 'http(80)',
                Proto    => 'tcp'
            )
            or die "Could not connect to :80!! $!";         

$sock2->send($req2);


sleep 5;


my $abc;
while(<$sock2>) {
        print $_;
    }


$sock->send($req);


sleep 5;


while(<$sock>) {
        print $_;
    }
```